# A fair coin is flipped 4 times. Probability of heads on the first 2 flips followed by 2 tails/all heads or all tails

Tags: combinatorics

First is the probability of heads on the first $2$ flips, followed by $2$ tails.

For this I got $1/16$. This is because there is only one way of getting $2$ heads on the first two flips. And $1$ way of getting $2$ tails on the last two flips. Hence, I got $1/16$.

The probability of all heads or all tails. For this, I did the same thing. There is only one way to get all heads and one way to get all tails. Hence, the final solution would be $2/16$.

Could someone confirm if my thought process is correct?

Comment: How many possible outcomes do you think there are when a coin is flipped $4$ times?

Comment: 16. I edited it. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Jones it is correct :)